# Python how to learn about importing files etc

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python programming, i'm familiar with the very basic stuff and i'm currently learning about creating function definitions in scripts.

In particular i'm a mac user and i'm using text wrangler to write and run my python programmes.

Now that i have learned how to define basic functions in scripts i have questions which my notes do not seem to answer.

How do i import my definition which is saved in a file on my desktop to use on IDLE? I've tried

import fileaname

in IDLE and it does not work.

Secondly Suppose i create a function A in one script and then another function B in a separate script that depends on A, do i have to import A in the script for B first? Do they need to be saved in the same file?

I appreciate any advice and useful tips.

Comment: Read the material about import statements in the Python tutorial.  Python imports files in directories.  To import something on the desktop, you would have to know what directory corresponds to the desktop.  I have no idea what that is on OSX.  On Windows, I believe it has changed from version to version, so I would not try it myself ;-).

Answer (score 0):

With import filename , you want to make sure its in the same directory as your original file.  Try using this too

```
import sys

sys.path.append(directory_path)
```

It seems to be a common issue.

Comment: I've opened up a folder on my Desktop and i've saved two scripts with two functions written in text wrangler in each file. Now the function in one file needs the use of the one in the other file, i've tried importing it in the script but it saying the definition is not recognised? Any tips?